# How to sort posts to keep new top rated posts at top

Tags: sorting

Lets say we have a website with posts.
The information we can get is:

```
post_time (from site launch)(doesn't change)
post_rating (changes over time)
number_of_comments (changes over time)
```

what would be a good formula in order for the website to keep fresh and good posts at the top without seeing the same post at the top again.

I figured I should give "weights" to each of the fields above, where
post_time will have the heaviest weight.

What kind of sorting does 9gag use for instance?

the difference between post_time can vary between 1 second and minutes/hours

edit:

Clarification:
I have a database where I keep all of this information, what I need
is a formula that will keep the posts page up to date and a user that logs now and in 20 minutes will see different posts.

Answer (score -1):

Ok so the simplest way I found is as follows:

- Add an additional DATE field to the Posts SQL table that is called top_date
- Select from the posts table all highest ratings that has top_date NULL
- update top_date of a wanted post with current time stamp

now the posts page will use DESC by top_date.

also there can be a function that will be called every few minutes that will
gather the top rating (RATING ONLY) posts without top_date and randomly choose
one to be updated.

If i was unclear feel free to ask any question here or in private message.